# Sharepoint 2010 groupid

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to Sharepoint! I'm trying to set up a group calendar with a default view showing all group members. I'm following this [guide](http://vbcity.com/blogs/skullcrusher/archive/2012/06/12/autopopulate-sharepoint-2010-group-calendar-with-team-members.aspx) which refers to a GroupID. Where can I find this? I've found a number of VB scripted resources but do not have VB installed (I have BIDS SSIS?). Is there a means of finding this via Sharepoint designer or by some other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the groups page where you would add and remove members from a group. The group ID will be an integer that you can find in the query string portion of the URL when you click on the desired group.

Comment: Many thanks! Obvious once you know where to look! :-)